# Write a function to exit the program, which automatically generates usernames based on the first letter of the first and last name

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am writing program based on this instructions:
Write a function to exit the program, which automatically generates usernames based on the first letter of the first and last name and saves the entries in the dictionary.

For example: Brad Pitt --> bpitt

- When the user no longer wants to enter names, write STOP.
- Then the program asks him: Do you want to leave the program (yes / no)?

  - If the user enters "yes", the program ends with the greeting "Thank you for using".
  - If the user enters "no", the program continues to ask for first and last name.
  - If the user does not enter "yes" or "no", the program asks him if he really wants to leave the program until he enters one of the mentioned options.

At the end the program displays the contents of the dictionary.

I write this:

```
dict = {}

while True:
    x = input('Enter name and surname: ').lower()
    if x != 'STOP':
    def name(s):
        l = s.split()
        new = ''
        for i in range(len(l) - 1):
            s = l[i]
            new += s[0]
        new += l[-1]
        return new

    s = x
    print(name(s))
    dict[x] = (name(s))
elif x == 'STOP':
    a = input('Do you want to leave the program (yes / no)? ')
    if a == 'Yes':
        print('Thank you for using.')
        exit()
    elif a == 'No':
        if x != 'STOP':
            def name(s):
                l = s.split()
                new = ''
                for i in range(len(l) - 1):
                    s = l[i]
                    new += s[0]
                new += l[-1]
                return new
            s = x
            print(name(s))
    else:
        a = input('Do you want to leave the program (yes / no)? ')
        if a == 'Yes':
            print('Thank you for using.')
            print(dict)
            exit()
        elif a == 'No':
            x = input('Enter name and surname: ')
            if x != 'STOP':
                def name(s):
                    l = s.split()
                    new = ''
                    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
                        s = l[i]
                        new += s[0]
                    new += l[-1]
                    return new
                s = x
                print(name(s))
```

At first it worked somehow, but not properly. Now I have made a mistake that I cannot find, because I am totally lost. Is there any easier way to write this code including function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your basic question, yes there is an easier way to write this code including the function.  To begin, lets look at your basic coding style.

1. Using the variable name ***dict*** is a bad idea, since this can and will be confused with the builtin dict structure.  This can lead to confusion in understand ing the code as well as subtle errors in execution should the compiler confuser your variable for the builtin function.
2. The creation of the function name is a great idea, since it splits out this operation into a separately executable and testable piece of code.  Embedding thise function within the while loop is not such a good idea since it is unnecessary and I believe reduces the efficiency of the overall python script.
3. exit is a helper function for for the interactive shell and is not needed in this application

The following is my recommendations for improving your script.

```
def name(s):
    l = s.lower().split()
    new = ''
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        s = l[i]
        new += s[0]
        new += l[-1]
    return new  

def createDict():
    names_dict = dict()
    while True:
        indata = input('Enter name and surname: ')
        if indata.lower() == 'stop':
            indata = input('Do you want to leave the program (yes / no)? ')
            if indata.lower()[0] == 'y':
                print('Thank you for using.')
                print(names_dict)
                break      
        else:
            nm = name(indata)
            print(nm)
            names_dict[indata] = nm
```

To run use `createDict()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your explanation helps me a lot in understanding this, thanks!!